# Best way to import many xml files using php without knowing any of the xml files format first?

Tags: php, xml

I've come up with some functions but I'm not confident in them being the best approach. Here is one I made for establishing what I call headers because I do the same thing with .csv files and the $headers array is used to create a database table, with headers being column names. I want to do the same with .xml files...

```
function ecsvi_XML_establish_headers($xmlpath){
if( ! $xml3 = simplexml_load_file( $xmlpath ) ) { 
    return false;     
} else { 
    $headers = array();

    foreach( $xml3->book[0]->attributes() as $a => $b ) { 
        $headers[] = $a;
    } 

    foreach( $xml3 as $header => $book ) { 
        foreach($book as $node => $value){
            $headers[] = $node;
        }
        break;
    }

    return $headers;
}
```

I'm testing with a .xml file that contains books, so that function as you can see contains the word "book". That is not suitable because it needs to work with any .xml file out there.

A function for counting what I'm calling "items" just to generalize things will currently return zero for the obvious reason (if you consider we are using any .xml file out there)...

```
function ecsvi_XML_count_number_of_items($xmlpath){
    $table = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents($xmlpath));
    return count($table->Row); 
}
```

This would not be suitable because it uses "Row" and I won't have elements called "Row" in my .xml files.

So I find myself wondering if I should using functions like eval() to perform the same lines of code or is there a more SimpleXML approach or other PHP functions I should be considering?

I've seen interfaces that output a .xml files content and then the user selects attributes and nodes etc to tell the application what to do. I want to avoid that if possible. The goal is to import any .xml to a database table that is created based on that very file. The script won't know the contents, elements, nodes, children etc.

Here is my book .xml file...

```
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
```

$headers outputs an array with the following...

```
*id
*author
*title
*genre
*price
*publish_date
*description
```

I need this list of headers to create a database table just for this .xml file. Each imported .xml file will be totally different and so no functions can use any of the items in that list or "catalog" or "book". Maybe I've made that clear to be sure.

Thanks for any advice on the best approach and existing source that could help me determine a suitable approach.

Answer (score 0):

No method is "magic".
You just simply cannot write an algorithm that would fit with
any XML format.

It's like asking :
"I would like to write a video player that will be able to read any video codec, even the one that have not been implemented yet."

So first, you need to reduce the field of application :
When you say : "Any XML format".

First : Why would you need to import "any" XML file in a tabular way ?
most of XML files do simply not have a tabular structure and there is no way to make in fit into a table-like structure.

Who is providing you those XML files ? For which purpose ? Can they provide a list of expected schema so you can find a pattern ?

For instance, if you know that all your files will be a "tabular" XML format in the form of

```
<first-level-element-we-dont-care>
    <item-element> 
        <header-name-1>some-value</header-name-1>
        <header-name-2>some value</header-name-2>
        <header-name-3>some value</header-name-3>
    </item-element>
    <item-element> 
        <header-name-1>some-value</header-name-1>
        <header-name-2>some value</header-name-2>
        <header-name-3>some value</header-name-3>
    </item-element>
</first-level-element-we-dont-care>
```

Then you can do something ...

First, using **SimpleXML** won't work here, because **SimpleXML** transform the XML Tree into objects for which you need to know the attribute names in advance (or you need to use introspection).

Instead, try to use a regular DOM API : https://www.php.net/dom
Then you could do the following in pseudo-code :

```
topEl = doc.rootElement();
firstItem = topEl.children()[0];
headers = [];
foreach(headerEl : firstItem.children()) {
   header.add(headerEl.tagName()); 
}
items = [];
foreach(itemEl : topEl.children()) {
   items.add([]); 
   foreach(header : headers) {
      items[-1][header] = itemEl.getElementByTagName(header).value();
   }
}
```

Comment: There is a Wordpress plugin that contains a library of XML PHP functions which reads the structure of any .xml file, displays it on screen and automatically establishes what is known as tokens.

Comment: It is called WP All Importer. The plugin itself has loads of bugs but the XML library was written by two developers, different names from the plugin author and that library seems sound. However WebTechGlobal does not use other developers libraries to create commercial products so we still need to come up with an approach on our own. Also the this library is extensive and I'm finding it hard to decide if its overkill or not. Thanks for replying I'm going to play around with your approach for a bit, still getting a feel for the best direction to go on this.